# Confusion in differentiation in physics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, differentiation

Here, we had to find theta such that the denominator has the maximum value. Being new to differentiation I basically didn't understand how differentiation solved the purpose:

[image]

I basically didnt understand why we differentiated it.

Comment: The differential of a cosine function is minus sine and the differential of a sine function is plus cosine.

Comment: @Farcher I've made an edit to the question. We had to find theta such that the denominator has the maximum value. I basically didn't understand how differentiation solved the purpose

Comment: At a local maximum of a function, the derivative is zero. The text says they are searching for the maximum, so they set the derivative equal to zero.

Comment: Essentially a maths question, but I don't think it's worth migrating, since it's pretty much answered by @KarstenKoop. Expansion: if a function $f(x)$ has a maximum at $x=x_0$, the points immediately either side of $x_0$ have a smaller function value. The derivative of $f(x)$ gives the slope of the tangent to the curve defined by $f(x)$. If the tangent line is ascending, its slope and hence the derivative of $f(x)$ are positive. If the tangent is descending, it's negative. So on one side of a maximum the derivative will be positive, on the other negative. Exactly at the maximum it's zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mere math.

In the maximum or minimum points, the slope of the curve is zero. And the differentiation (the derivative) *is* the slope. So, set the derivative equal to zero, and the solutions are the peaks and valleys on the curve.

[image]

http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Calculus/SignsOfDer/MaxMin.htm